# Catch only "sub-exceptions" of a main exception type without magic strings

Tags: .net, exception

There's the `System.InvalidOperationException` exception, but it's thrown based on multiple conditions, a few of which are as follows:

```
Sequence contains more than one element
Sequence contains no elements
```

I don't want to handle every `System.InvalidOperationException`.  I may only want to just handle `Sequence contains no elements` while allowing the others to be thrown normally, but the only way it seems to do this is to use a magic string to match the exception message which is not safe for obvious reasons.

Is there any safe means to handle individual exceptions that roll up to a main type?

**Update:**  For anyone wondering why I don't use `.SingleOrDefault` and check for null, it's because I am doing this:

```
DbcColumn = DbcTable?.Columns.Single(c => c.ColumnName.NonCaseEquals(FieldName));
```

Note the `?`.  If DbcTable is null, it won't evaluate the rest of the expression and DbcColumn will be null.  If I use SingleOrDefault, DbcColumn will be null, but I won't know if it's because DbcTable was null or if SingleOrDefault didn't find a match.  It keeps me from having to do this:

```
if (DbcTable != null)
{
    DbcColumn = DbcTable.Columns.SingleOrDefault(c => c.ColumnName.NonCaseEquals(FieldName));

    if (DbcColumn == null)
    {
        throw new Exception($"{nameof(DbcColumn)} {FieldName} not found in {DbcTable.DatabaseName}.{DbcTable.TableName}");
    }
}
```

So I guess what I want to do is not possible.

Comment: A better way to handle the errors you describe is not to let them be thrown in the first place. For example, to avoid "Sequence contains no elements", you could, say, use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First` and check for null.  Similarly for the other cases.

Comment: @Joe See update to my question for why I am wanting to do this.

Comment: So you wanted a better exception strategy to be able to differentiate exceptions, Then you go ahead and throw `Exception` instead of a more specific one? Practice what you preach ;)

Comment: @jgauffin I don't have an aversion to general exceptions.  I just want to be able to catch different subexceptions.  Besides, I planned on creating a `ColumnNotFound` exception, but it woudn't matter anyway because all I am interested in is throwing an exception with a custom message to be picked up by ELMAH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific example, no.  Looking at those different exceptions, they both have the same properties other than the `Message`, so there's nothing safer than that to distinguish them.

Obviously you can use *preventative* measures like `Any()`, `Count()`, `SingleOrDefault()` etc. to determine if an operation *would* throw an exception, but there's nothing better than the message to distinguish those two problems.

Answer (score 1):

try using `SingleOrDefault()` on your object and then check if the the object is null. If the object is null, then you know that it does not contain any element, however if it throws an exception then you know that it contains more than one element !

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different strategy:

```
DbcColumn = DbcTable?.Columns
                     .Where(c => c.ColumnName.NonCaseEquals(FieldName))
                     .Take(2);
if (DbcColumn == null || DbcColumn.Count == 2)
   //uhh ohh
```